# How do I find the hash value with the biggest key?

Tags: ruby, hash, key, max

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  How do I find an entry in a hash with the greatest key value?  I have this hash

```
a = {1 => [1, 2], 2 => [3, 4, 5]}
```

Right now, I'm doing this

```
[a.keys.max, a[a.keys.max]]
```

but I figure there's a slicker way to pull this off.

Comment: What's wrong with that? Does `a.max_by { |k, _v| k }` work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
k, v = hash.max_by { |key, value| key }
```

Comment: ...or `a.max_by(&:first)`.

Comment: Technically yes. It doesn't communicate intention though. We want to sort by key. `first` does not reveal an intention here, the order of key and value is arbitrary.

Comment: I don't follow. As I'm sure you know, when a hash is the receiver of an enumerable method, each key-value pair of the hash is passed as an array to the block, in key-value order, so this variant of your method yields the same result.

Comment: I'm making an argument about human factors. The english word `first` does not mean `key` and hence the code does not reveal intention. That is "intention revealing" vs "implementation revealing"

Answer (score 0):

Also, `#max` find the largest `key` by default:

```
> a = {1 => [1, 2], 6 => [-1], 3 => [0] }
> a.max
#=> [6, [-1]]
```